# CSS inconsistancy, image not displaying correctly

Tags: css

The link to the content can be seen here: http://bit.ly/K6jRGI

The issue is that our black line divider is not showing between Home and Guide.

The divider is showing for all apart from the first two buttons.

Does anyone know why this is, and what I'm missing?

```
.top_menu ul li{
list-style: none;
background: url("images/bg_li.gif") no-repeat right center transparent;
float: left;
padding-top: 2px;
margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Firebug, on line 241 of `style.css`:

```
.top_menu ul li:first-child {
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: Okay, that was quite dumb. Thank you very much. I'll tick you in 5 minutes when it lets me.

Comment: Always remember, firebug is your friend